# trying to open an application by clicking button but getting an error

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
import os
root = Tk()
root.title("menu")
root.geometry("400x400")


def open_aoe():
    os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Age of Empires Definitive Edition\AoEDE_s.exe")


btn = Button(root, text="AOE", command=open_aoe)
btn.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

erorr:'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

It cant find the files because of the folder names (there's space)
you should put quotes to handle folder names with space

example:

```
os.system('"' +"C:\Program Files (x86)\Age of Empires Definitive Edition\AoEDE_s.exe" + '"')
```

Comment: Hi Ismi, I do have quotes around the C: path so why did the extra qoutes u added work?